# Running a piece of code at certain intervals

Tags: php

So what i want here is to be able to run a piece of code one time every minute but I'm not really sure how to achieve this. I heard about cron jobs but from what i gathered in my research they are best used on a linux servers, and since i'm running localhost on windows 7 I don't think that's an option. Here is the code that i want to run:

```
if($ks->onlineCheck())
{
   $ks->redirect($location);
}
```

This above is the code i would like to run every minute and then redirect the user to a certain location if the onlineCheck() method returns true.

I'm really open for suggestions here and I hope that someone will be able to point me in the right direction.

Comment: Usually remote server is Linux based. You can test cron script on windows via CLI, also, there is no "redirects user" in crone, it's pure CLI.

Comment: If this is a question about a web application, use JavaScript. PHP alone won't allow you to do anything dynamic.

Comment: Hm in that case, i would probably avoid cron scripts, as i need this code ran on my index page. Is there are any other way i could achieve that?

Comment: The equivalent to cron on Windows platforms is scheduled tasks, under Administrative Tools from the System control panel

Comment: Another way is making a connection to a websocket. This way the php script can communicate both ways. It's not ideal however.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: (JavaScript)

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
        setInterval(function(){ window.location="http://www.newlocation.com"; },  10 * 60 * 1000); // Re-direct after every 10 min 
    });
```

Else you can do some R&D on sleep() function of PHP [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php)

Comment: sleep function will work properly at cli mode. in cgi or web server mode execution time depend "web server" and php both. so its tough to control sleep timing.

Comment: Okay, I didn't knew that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have following options to achieve -

1. You can do it completely by PHP CLI mode.
2. You can do it with the help of JavaScript time interval method by refreshing current page and calling your PHP script.
3. You can do it with the help of OS (in your case win provide schedule, and other OS like unix based system has cron job). In this case you may call your script through GUI or from CLI

here are some pros and cons -

1. PHP CLI need to run from command prompt, it will not run into any browser. So you may not get full functionality of your application if it depend on browser or GUI
2. JavaScript is possible to disable from client and it will not guaranteed to run in every browser or in every circumstances. But its good solution if you need small resource/footprint.
3. OS depended solution is relatively better that above two others for huge script that required too much resource.